# List View doesn't show link in Site

Tags: list-view, force.com-sites, guest-user

I have created a Force.com site in my org and want to display the standard Contact List View page.

I am having the problem that although the user can directly access the Contacts by pasting the link, i.e. http://namespace-developer-edition.na15.force.com/003i000000Myiu, the Contacts do not appear as hyperlinks on the List View page (http://namespace-developer-edition.na15.force.com/003/o) like this:

[image: list view page]

I have done the following as far as permissions are concerned for the Site Profile:

- Enabled all FLS
- Given Read and Create access to the Contact object (these are the only options that appear)
- Granted the Site access to all Apex Classes/VF Pages in my org, as well as all "Site Standard Pages"
- Granted access to both Contact Record Types used
- Have Public Read/Write sharing default for the Contact Object

The List View links show up fine in my non-site org... it must be something to do with permissions.  I even tried using an  for the Contact object but got the same result, no links.

It must be a permissions issue, but what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of your list views to Visible to certain groups of users, and specify the groups to share to. List views whose visibility is set to Visible to all users may be visible to public users of your site. To share a list view with public users, create a new public group for those users and give them visibility. If the object's sharing is set to private, public users won't be able to see those records, regardless of list view visibility.

Comment: Yes, I read this, but it's not the problem.  I can see the List Views, and the records, I just can't click on them.